# SolrNet in CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: solrnet, clrstoredprocedure

Has anyone ever used Solrnet inside CLR Stored Procedures? I would really appreciate pointers to some good tutorials.

One problem I'm facing is that I can't find a way to include the SolrNet library as a reference to the VS (2008) Database (SQL Server) Project.

**Update:**

So it seems that when you have an SQL Server Project, and you want to add a reference to a library, it has to first exist in SQL Server itself, which makes sense. This is done by creating an assembly in SQL Server from the DLL itself with the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY SolrNet FROM 'C:\CLR_SP\SolrNet.dll' 
WITH   PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

(Note that *UNSAFE* might have some repercussions on the security of the database however it is ok for me for now)

However the SolrNet.dll requires other library dependencies such as *Castle.Windsor.dll* (which in itself requires *System.Core.dll*) and *Ninject.dll*. I found the required version of *Castle.Windsor.dll* (which is 2.5.1.0) and also *System.Core.Dll* (which was in the .Net folder of Windows), however I cannot find the required version of *Ninject.dll* (which should be 2.1.0.76). I have attempted to create assembly version 2.2 but, as expected, it did not do the job.

I searched for it on different repositories but could not find it. Does anyone know where I could find this version of DLL?

**Update 2:**

So after lots of searching over the net, I still didn't manage to find *Ninject.dll v2.1.0.76*. My next attempt was to use the next version of SolrNet (which is v0.4.0.2002). This version required *Ninject.dll v2.2* which I had already found. So my current status is registering all other libraries in SQL Server which are dependencies of *SolrNet.dll*. I will leave this open to document my process just in case there will be someone having the same problem.

**Update 3:**

I have managed to register all required libraries (some of which I got from SolrNet source on [GitHub](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/lib)). So now, SolrNet is registered as an assembly in SQL Server, and therefore I can reference it from the .NET SQL Server Project (for creating the CLR Stored Procedure). So I have written a very simple CLR SP which connects to SOLR and retrieves a piece of data. Code below:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void PrintToday()
{
    SqlPipe p;
    p = SqlContext.Pipe;
    p.Send("Helloooo");

    // Open Solr instance
    SolrNet.Startup.Init<ActiveProduct>("http://192.168.2.190:8983/solr");

    // Get instance of ActiveProduct
    ISolrOperations<ActiveProduct> operations = ActiveProduct.GetActiveProductSolrOperations();

    // Prepare QueryOptions. This will be passed as a parameter into the query() method.
    SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.QueryOptions qo = new QueryOptions();

    qo.Start = 0;
    qo.Rows = 20;

    // Query Solr
    SolrQueryResults<ActiveProduct> results = operations.Query(new SolrQueryByField("SearchDescription", "pants"), qo);

    // Read results
    String s = "Docs found: " + results.NumFound;
    p.Send(s);
}
```

My next problem is that when I deploy and run the CLR SP, an error is popping stating that Solr is already registered in container. The exact output that I see in SQL Server Management Studio is the following:

```
Helloooo
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PrintToday, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'PrintToday': 
System.ApplicationException: Key 'SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.CLRStoredProcedures2.ActiveProduct.SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection' already registered in container
System.ApplicationException: 
   at SolrNet.Utils.Container.Register(String key, Type serviceType, Converter`2 factory)
   at SolrNet.Utils.Container.Register[T](String key, Converter`2 factory)
   at SolrNet.Startup.Init[T](ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Startup.Init[T](String serverURL)
   at StoredProcedures.PrintToday()
```

*PrintToday* is the name of the CLR StoredProcedure

*CLRStoredProcedures2* is the name of the .NET SQL Server project and default namespace in VS 2008

*ActiveProduct* is the name of the document in Solr, and the cs class with Solr annotations

As can be seen from the output, the first `Pipe.send("Hellooo")` is doing its job therefore the SP works fine until there.

When I searched for the above error, I found out that it will show when one tries to register Solr instance twice in the same application. Now I don't see where I am registering the instance twice. Am I missing something here?

Note that the above cs function worked fine when executed in a cs console application developed on my machine. Another detail which might be important is that the SOLR Server is being hosted on my machine which is on the same network of my SQL Server 2005.

**Update 4:**

For starters, the error I mentioned above (in update 3) does not fire when the SP is executed the 1st time just after deployment (let's assume that the 1st time works for now since I have another error which I'm currently working on fixing), the error fires when the SP is executed again afterwards. So it seems that whatever `SolrNet.Startup.Init<ActiveProduct>("http://192.168.2.190:8983/solr");` is doing (creating some sort of session that has to do with a container I think) when called from the SP it is not releasing the "session" therefore the 2nd time (and each time afterwards) the SP is executed, the error is fired. Is there a way to sort of stop the session or releasing from the container. What I can do as a workaround is to `try - catch` the `SolrNet.Startup.Init` part, however this is not clean.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to use SolrNet inside a CLR Stored Procedure?

Comment: Currently I have certain logic (database related) in a stored procedure. This stored procedure is being called from many places so I don't wish to replace it with .net code. Now I would like to get data from a Solr instance inside this stored procedure.

Comment: Did you have any concrete issues using SolrNet in SQL-CLR? If so, please post it. Otherwise I don't think the question is a good fit for Stackoverflow...

Comment: Hi Mauricio, I was looking for some tutorials. With regards to concrete issues, I'm having difficulties to include the SolrNet library into the project. Note that I am trying to include it into a .Net Database Project in VS 2008.

Comment: SolrNet does *not* require Castle.Windsor.dll or Ninject.dll. But when you don't use an external IoC container, it does require Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll.

Comment: Ic, but when I attempted to register the SolrNet library in SQL Server, an error stating that SolrNet references an assembly _Ninject_ or _Castle.._ does not exist was given. Only after registering those libraries (and a bunch of other ones) could I register SolrNet library. I have made some progress (as documented in **Update 3** above in the question) but still stuck in the _...already registered in container_ error.

Comment: @mrd3650 : use the SolrNet.dll from the 'unmerged' directory.

Comment: Oh ic, that one will not ask for dependencies that's right. thanks. Mauricio, could you help me with regards to Update 4 above? I.e. the 'already in container' issue? That is the only 'minor' sort of issue I have left. Otherwise the SP did the job; that is I am receiving data in a CLR SP from SOLR, which was my final aim.

Comment: @mrd3650 use a lazy value to ensure a single initialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mauricio. I will check this out as soon as I have time. Could you post it as an answer to the question so that I can mark as correct if it works as required?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer The problem with Lazy value is that it is only introduced in .NET 4.0 and later, while I'm using .NET 3.5. However I think the job can still be done with the Singleton Pattern, which is similar to what the Lazy value achieves.

Comment: @mrd3650 yes, or backport Lazy, it's pretty easy. Or use FSharp.Core.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to summarize the steps / requirements with explanations whenever possible:

- For some reason SQL Server seems to trigger the "hidden" dependencies of the merged SolrNet. Usually you can just use the merged SolrNet (which includes all integration modules) and if you ignore the integration classes the dependencies won't trigger. But in this case the unmerged SolrNet is necessary.
- SolrNet does HTTP requests to the Solr server, so the DLL must be registered with [UNSAFE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx) permissions in SQL-CLR.
- SolrNet Initialization (Startup.Init) must happen only once per application, but you don't have a 'root' context in SQL-CLR to place this initialization. A workaround is to use a singleton or a [Lazy type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx). SQL-CLR doesn't run .NET 4 yet, but you can backport the Lazy type or use FSharp.Core.dll's implementation (I [blogged about this](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/10/10-reasons-to-use-f-runtime-in-your-c.html) some time ago)

Comment: thanks for the summary. One question regarding the Lazy/Singleton thing.. How can I check whether Solr instance is already initialized? I was assuming that when I call `ISolrOperations<Doc> oprs = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Doc>>();` I will get a NULL in `oprs` when it is not initialized, however I'm getting a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception instead. So what I need is to somehow check whether Solr Instance is already initialized or not. THanks.

Comment: @mrd3650 call your Lazy/Singleton initialization every time.